# How do i fix a "claim" button that displays for the Loser and Winner when it should only be for the Winner

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, ejs

I have 1v1 browser games on my website & I'm trying to make a button show up for the winner & not show up for the loser.

HTML for Button:

```
<div class="modal__overlay close-disable" data-modal="end-screen">
  <div class="modal">
    <h2 class="modal__title" data-ending-text>The game has ended!</h2>
    <div class="modal__info flex flex-center">
      <span> Wager: <%= locals.game.wager %></span>
      <img
        src="<%= locals.game.cryptoImg %>"
        class="modal__crypto-icon"
        alt=""
      />
    </div>
    <button
      class="button button--secondary button--small modal__button"
      data-button="claim"
    >
      Claim Prize
    </button>
```

JS Used to define Winner:

```
clumsyBirdSocket.on('game-finished', () => {
  isGameOver = true;
  endGame();
})

clumsyBirdSocket.on('opponent-left', () => {
  isGameOver = true;
  showEndScreen();
});

// HTML selectors
const statusText = document.querySelector('[data-status-text]')
const endingText = document.querySelector('[data-ending-text]');
const endScreenModal = document.querySelector('[data-modal="end-screen"]');


// global variables
let isGameOver = false;
let isPlayerDead = false;
let gameStarted = false;
let scores = {
  player: 0,
  opponent: 0
}

function endGame() {
  if(!isGameOver) return;
  let text;
  if(scores.player > scores.opponent) {
    text = TEXTS.win;
  } else if(scores.player < scores.opponent) {
    text = TEXTS.lose;
    document.getElementById("claim").style.display="none";
  } else {
    text = TEXTS.draw;
  }
  text += `<br> Scores: ${scores.player} - ${scores.opponent}`;

  showEndScreen(text);
}

function showEndScreen(text = TEXTS.opponentForfeited) {
  endingText.innerHTML = text;
  statusText.innerText = "";
  statusText.classList.remove('text-waiting');
  endScreenModal.classList.add('active');
}
```

If i add

```js
document.getElementById("claim").style.display="none"
```

Under the `"function endGame"` Takes the issue out Temporarily, When the player who WON claims there prize and returns to lobby it then prompts the Loser with the claim Prize button.. Hence why its a temporary fix. Any direction Helps.

Comment: You can remove the element with `document.getElementById("claim").remove()`.

Comment: To make it more secure you have to do the checking and adding server side.

Comment: the .remove unfortunately did not do anything :/

Comment: Sorry I can't understand what's wrong with `display: none`?

Comment: so the display="none" removes the Modal from popping up for the Loser... But... after the winner Claims Prize and then "clicks" the return to lobby button. The Modal then pops up for the loser saying claim prize

Comment: I dont understand it either thats why i am here!

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'remove') That was for the .remove and......Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style') for the style.display="none"

Comment: It means that the browser cannot find the `claim` element. Replace `document.getElememtById("claim")` with `document.getElementsByClassName("modal__button")[0]`

Comment: do i add the style.display="none"  after [0]? i tried it with just document.getElementsByClassName("modal__button")[0]; and it did nothing, still popping up for the Loser.. i think you are on to something tho so Thank you for your help

Comment: Yes add it at the back.

Comment: Lets go! That fixed it.. Thank you so much.. but now the endGame modal doesnt popup after the game unless you click somewhere on the screen. You are a huge help and that answered my question, if you want to help further feel free. Thanks again